# iOS, how to restart NSThread?

Tags: ios, nsthread

To restart the NSSthread, I'm using the code below:

```
- (IBAction)listen:(id)sender {
thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(listen1) object:nil];
[thread start];
[thread cancel];
[thread start];
}
```

But when I built and pressed this button, I've received error: "attempt to start the thread again"
Can you help me?

Comment: remove the first [thread start];  which is before [thread cancel]; and also add your listen1 method here for description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `-cancel` doesn't stop the thread, it just sets cancel flag.

> Changes the **cancelled state** of the receiver to indicate that it **should** exit.
>
> `- (void)cancel`
>
> The semantics of this method are the same as those used for the `NSOperation` object. This method **sets state information** in the receiver that is then reflected by the `isCancelled` method. Threads that support cancellation should periodically call the `isCancelled` method to determine if the thread has in fact been cancelled, and exit if it has been.

You can stop a Thread only from within itself by calling `[NSThread exit]`.

---

By the way, what are you trying to achieve? Starting separate thread is almost never good idea and starting the same thread twice is twice wrong.